# ttk bootstrap tableview: I want to have a another row color when value[-1] is not 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, ttkbootstrap

i'm new to ttkbootstrap and i want to convert my treeview widget to ttkbootstrap.
In treeview i changed the row color when a specif trigger is met.

For this i created several differnt tags, is something similar in tableview possible?

```
        tree_frame = Frame(root, bg='black')
        tree_frame.pack(pady=5)
        codex_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, yscrollcommand=tree_scroll.set, selectmode="extended", height=14)
        ...
        codex_tree.tag_configure('odd', background='lightblue')
        codex_tree.tag_configure('even', background='white')
        codex_tree.tag_configure('odd_new', background='lightgreen', font=('Arial', 9, 'bold'))
        codex_tree.tag_configure('even_new', background='#26D5B3', font=('Arial', 9, 'bold'))
        codex_tree.tag_configure('header', background='ivory3', font=('Arial', 9, 'bold'))
        ...
        for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
              if idx % 2 == 1:
                   if entry[9] == 1:
                        tags = ('odd_new',)
                   else:
                        tags = ('odd',)
              else:
                   if entry[9] == 0:
                        tags = ('even_new',)
                   else:
                        tags = ('even',)

            codex_tree.insert('', 'end', values=new_entry, tags=tags)
```

i changed the tableview.py in def build_table_data(self, coldata, rowdata):

```
            if int(values[-1]) > 0:
                  self.apply_table_stripes(('black', 'white'))
            else:
                  self.apply_table_stripes(('black', 'green'))
```

but this didn't work.